# Getting Bad Request 400 when doing post request

Tags: c#, .net, api, http

I'm getting a bad request 400 when I'm trying to make a post request to an api. It works fine in Postman so I can't find out what causes the problem. Get requests works fine from the same Api, but not when I do post requests.

```
        var accessToken = GetAccessTokenAsync().Result.AccessToken;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var data = new Object() 
        { 
            Name = "name", 
            PhoneNumber = "phone", 
            Street = "address", 
            Town = "city", 
            PostalCode = "postalCode", 
            Country = "country"
        };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(postUrl, data))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Response root = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Response>();
                return root;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }

public class Object
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string Result { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: if it works fine in post man, you can view c# code in postman and compare to your code

Comment: Is your object being serialised to the correct casing?

Comment: What is the body content you are sending in POSTMan? For example, does the server need a valid country code or phone number and wont accept any random string? Also, you get the code, but what does the response _body_ say?

Comment: Thank you OneCricketeer! It had to do with the phone number. I double checked and it needed to start with a +. Thanks for the heads up.